# Recognizing similar shapes at random scale and translation

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, fft, image-recognition

Playing around with finding stuff on a graphical screen, I'm currently at a loss about how to find a given shape within an image. The shape in the image could have a different scale and will be at some unknown x,y offset, of course.

Aside from pixel artifacts resulting from different scales, there is also a little noise in both images, so I need a somewhat tolerant search.

Here's the image I am looking for.

[image: Farmerama frame]

It should show up somewhere in a screen dump of my (dual) screen buffer, roughly 3300 x 1200 pixels in size. I'd of course expect to find it in a browser window, but that information shouldn't be necessary.

The object of this exercise (so far) is to come up with a result that says:

- Yes, the wooden frame (of that approximate color and that, possibly slightly truncated, shape) was found on my screen (or not); and
- the game's client area (the black area inside the frame) occupies the rectangle from `(x1,y1)` to `(x2,y2)`.

I would like to be robust against scaling and the noise that's likely to be introduced by dithering. On the other hand, I can rule out some of the usual CV challenges, such as rotation or non-rigidity. That frame shape is dead easy for the human brain to discern, how hard can it be for a dedicated piece of software? This is an Adobe Flash application, and until recently I had thought that perceiving the images from a game GUI should be easy as pie.

I'm looking for an algorithm that is able to find the x,y translation at which the greatest possible overlap between the needle and haystack occur, and if possible without having to be iterated through a series of possible scale factors. Ideally, the algorithm could abstract out the "shape-ness" of the images in a way that's independent of scale.

I've read some interesting things about Fourier Transforms to accomplish something similar: Given a target image at the same scale, FFT and some matrix math yielded up the points in the bigger image that corresponded to the search pattern. But I don't have the theoretical background to put this into practice, nor do I know if this approach will gracefully handle the scale problem. Help would be appreciated!

Technology: I'm programming in Clojure/Java but could adapt algorithms in other languages. I think I should be able to interface with libraries that follow C calling conventions but I would prefer a pure Java solution.

---

You may be able to understand why I've shied away from presenting the actual image. It's just a silly game, but the task of screen-reading it is proving much more challenging than I had thought.

I'm obviously able to do an exhaustive search of my screen buffer for the very pixels (excluding the black) that make up my image, and that even runs in under a minute. But my ambition was to find that wooden frame using a technique that would match the shape regardless of differences that might arise from scaling and dithering.

Dithering, in fact, is one of many frustrations I'm having with this project. I've been working on extracting some useful vectors by edge extraction, but edges are woefully elusive because the pixels of any given area have widely inconsistent colors - so it's hard to tell real edges from local dithering artifacts. I had no idea that such a simple-looking game would produce graphics that are so hard for software to perceive.

Should I start off by locally averaging pixels before I start looking for features? Should I reduce color depth by throwing out the least significant bits of the pixel color values?

I'm *trying* for a pure Java solution (actually programming in Clojure/Java mix) so I'm not wild about opencv (which installs .DLL's or .so's with C code). Please don't worry about my choice of language, the learning experience is much more interesting to me than performance.

Comment: It is not clear to what kind of frequency domain usage you are mentioning. My best guess, given the problem, is comparison by Fourier descriptors. These can be easily made rotation, translation, and scale invariant, thus helpful for your problem. You begin by extracting each contour of the connected components in your binary image, then sample each one and determine the Fourier descriptors. The same is done for the "needle" image. Then you can try matching shapes using these descriptors. But, there are many other methods for this task, depending on other hidden (forgotten) requirements.

Comment: Also check out SIFT and SURF if these algorithms aren't familiar to you; Gary Bradski's book Learning OpenCV can provide some guidance. Several commercial vision libraries ($$) have implementations of "robust shape matching" that simplify setup. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURF

Comment: Carl, could you post some of the original sample images (and/or a link to an archive of sample images)? Are you looking for a robust solution, an easy solution, a fun/complex solution just to test, or the "optimal" solution (for some problem domain/market)? There are statistical descriptors, Fourier descriptors, etc., but there are also techniques that may be a little easier to get your head around, and may work well enough for your purpose. (I also retagged your question to add "opencv" and "image-processing" so that it gets a bit more attention.)

Comment: @Rethunk, thank you for your attention and input! I've edited my question to make the purpose and parameters of the task a helluva lot more clear. Hope this helps!

Comment: @CarlSmotricz: It's trivial for those in the field to suggest an ultra-generic solution based on heavyweight libraries, but finding a simple solution that works without overkill is an interesting problem - see my answer for a suggestion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Being a computer vision guy, I would normally point to feature-extraction and -matching (SIFT, SURF, LBP, etc.), but this is almost certainly an overkill, since most of these methods offer more invariances (=tolerances against transformations) than you actually require (e.g. against rotation, luminance change,...). Also, using features would involve either OpenCV or *lots* of programming.

So here is my proposal for a simple solution - you judge whether it passes the smartness threshold:

It looks like the image you are looking for has some very distinct structures (the letters, the logos, etc). I would suggest that you do a pixel-to-pixel match for every possible translation, and for a number of different scales (I assume the range of scales is limited) - but **only for a small distinctive patch** of the image you are looking for (say, a square portion of the yellow text). This is much faster than matching the whole thing. If you want a fancy name for it: In image processing it's called template matching by correlation. The "template" is the thing you are looking for.

Once you have found a few candidate locations for your small distinctive patch, you can **verify** that you have a hit by testing either the whole image or, more efficiently, a few **other** distinctive patches of the image (using, of course, the translation / scale you found). This makes your search robust against accidental matches of the original patch without stealing too much performance.

Regarding dithering tolerance, I would go for simple pre-filtering of both images (the template you are looking for, and the image that is your search space). Depending on the properties of the dithering, you can start experimenting with a simple box blur, and probably proceed to a median filter with a small kernel (3 x 3) if that does not work. This will not get you 100% identity between template and searched image, but robust numerical scores you can compare.

**Edit in the light of comments**

I understand that (1) you want something more robust, more "CV-like" and a bit more fancy as a solution, and that (2) you are skeptical towards achieving scale invariance by simply scanning though a large stack of different scales.

**Regarding (1)**, the canonical approach is, as mentioned above, to use feature descriptors. Feature descriptors do not describe a complete image (or shape), but a small portion of an image in a way that is invariant against various transformations. Have a look at [SIFT](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/) and [SURF](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~surf/), and at [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org), which has a good SIFT implementation and also implements [MSER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions) and [HOG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) (and is much smaller than OpenCV). SURF  is easier to implement than SIFT, both are heavily patented. Both have an "upright" version, which has no rotation invariance. This should increase robustness in your case.

The strategy your describe in your comment goes more in the direction of shape descriptors than image feature descriptors. *Make sure that you understand the difference between those!* 2D shape descriptors aim at shapes which are typically described by an outline or a binary mask. Image feature descriptors (in the sense use above) aim at images with intensity values, typically photographs. An interesting shape descriptor is [shape context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_context), *many* others are summarized [here](http://math.uci.edu/icamp/summer/research/classification/shape_descriptors_survey_part3.pdf). I don't think that your problem is best solved by shape descriptors, but maybe I misunderstood something. I would be very careful with shape descriptors on image edges, as edges, being first derivatives, can be strongly altered by dithering noise.

**Regarding (2)**: I'd like to convince you that scanning through a bunch of different scales is not just a stupid hack for those who don't know Computer Vision! Actually, its done a lot in vision, we just have a fancy name for it to mislead the uninitiated - [scale space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space) search. That's a bit of an oversimplification, but really just a bit. Most image feature descriptors that are used in practice achieve scale invariance using a scale space, which is a stack of increasingly downscaled (and low-pass filtered) images. The only trick they add is to look for extrema in the scale space and compute descriptors only at those extrema. But still, the complete scale space is computed and traversed to find those extrema. Have a look in the [original SIFT paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/) for a good explanation of this.

Comment: Thank you for understanding, and a *very* sensible answer! Since I'm likely to only run on one computer, the exact pixel match would be quick and pragmatic. This silly sub-problem is actually keeping me away from much more fun stuff I hope to attack next! I want to "do" CV because I want to avoid feeling my app is completely fragile to imperceptible changes in the image, and because I hope what I learn will stand me in good stead later. At the moment I'm scanning Dr. Szeliski's book (http://szeliski.org/Book/) for tips. Box blurring coming up next.

Comment: To answer more directly to your suggestion: straight-on pixel matching "feels" too fragile to me, and I'm horrified at the thought of either providing guesses at the scale or zooming through a perhaps arbitrarily fine progression of test scales. I was hoping there was a way to represent shapes in both images in a (more or less) scale independent way. My latest approach involves turning detected edges into a set of vectors which I'd store and compare in polar (angle, magnitude) form; I could then check if the on-screen vector set contains the subset from my search image.

Comment: I edited my post in the light of your comments. It got rather long, sorry, but I wanted to address your points.

Comment: I'm going to hold off on the checkmark until the weekend on the off chance that a different CV guru swoops in to hand me the "magic" simple yet powerful and flexible solution I had been hoping for - it would be a shame to shut down my bounty earlier than necessary. But given your very helpful comments you are practically certain to "win." Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Nice. I once implemented some cheat on a flash game by capturing the screen as well :). If you need to find the exact border you gave in the image, you could create a color filter, thus removing all the rest and you end up with a binary image that you could use for further processing (the task at hand would be to find a matching rectangle with certain border ratio. Also, you could implement four kernels that would find the corners at a few different scales.

If you have a image stream, and know there is movement, you can also monitor the difference between frames to capture the action parts in your screen by employing a background modeling solution. Combine these and you will get quite far I guess, without resorting to more exotic methods, Like multi scale analysis and stuff.

It performance an issue? My cheat used about 20 fps as it needed to click a ball fast enough.

Comment: Color filtering won't do much for me as the colors in that image are very "mixed." If the colors were nicely homogenous I would have less of a problem. What *does* work is a straight pixel-for-pixel match, but of course I'd like to have a "smarter" solution than that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reporting back with an answer to my own question to let folks know where I ended up going with this.

---

Having not found or gotten any hints on my sought magic scale invariant shape descriptor, I decided to go with DCS' advice and perform pretty much straight pixel searching across the whole screen.

First I searched for a 512 x 60 chunk of the logo. But it turns out that what ends up being a quad nested loop (rows / columns of full image x rows / columns of search image) would run for over an hour, worst case. Unacceptable.

I was able to scale the problem down linearly by choosing a smaller search image, a patch of about 48 x 32 pixels. This took me to, I think, about 30 seconds, and was still slower than I would have liked. Also, time would be going up when I later tried to search for some other features.

My solution was to search only for a single scan line of my search image, and even that by proxy rather than completely. Because of the comic-color nature of the image I was searching, I decided that average color hues would make decent proxies for the pixels I was looking for. I selected the "middle" line of the search image, extracted the hue (as an integer between 0 and 7200) for each pixel, and computed the sum of those hue values. In the screen image, I computed a moving total over the number of pixels corresponding to the width of the search image, so for each pixel position I would need only to subtract out the oldest pixel and add in a single new one. Using Java's `Color.rgbToHSB` left some optimization potential, especially in light of the conversion to `float` and back, but the whole screen could be pre-sampled in a couple hundred ms.

So I created a list of differences between screen hue totals and that for my search image middle line, found the best (i.e. smallest) difference, and then did a full pixel-by pixel comparison for those positions that shared first place for best difference. There were usually less than 10 of those optimum color total matches, so 10 pixel-by-pixel comparisons took negligible time.

So now I'm finding my search image in about half a second, with some optimization potential still untapped. If I need to "do" more different scales, hopefully the different resolution will let me pick a different search image without trial and error, but in the worst case only a small part of the comparison work needs to be run multiple times, and I anticipate still staying under a second.

I've not met my original goal of being very resistant to different dithers (i.e. detail pixel renditions) of my sought images; my algorithm requires a good match on colors. But given how hard a problem it would be, I've decided I'll cross that bridge if I ever have to.

Comment: I'm surprised by the timings you report, especially the 30 sec with the 48x32 patch (which I think is a good patch size). However, I have no experience in image processing with Java; I use C++, sometimes Matlab. Patch correlation (which is what you do) is typically heavily optimized/parallized in C++ image processing APIs, using multithreading, SSE, Cuda, etc. You may be interested in the Java API  ImageJ, which claims to be "the world's fastest pure Java image processing program. It can filter a 2048x2048 image in 0.1 seconds.". See http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/

Comment: @DCS: Nice to see you're still interested! The timings are reported from my very imperfect memory and based on very unoptimized code in a language that isn't exactly a poster child for optimization. I felt it wouldbe helpful to get an idea of algorithm performance based on cruddy code before doing anything aimed specifically at performance. But given my current approach and its satisfactory performance, it looks like I can dispense with micro-optimization anyway - the ideal outcome! Thanks again for your helpful advice. I noticed ImageJ earlier but want to keep the big stuff in reserve.